# ng-class not correct on initial pageload

Tags: angularjs, angular-ng-class

This issue has been frustrating me for a while.

When loading the page, default sorting for a table is set via this code:

```
$scope.sort = {
     field: 'date',
     dir: 'asc'
};
```

Sorting is changed via user clicking on table headings, like so:

```
<th ng-class="{'sort-desc': sorted('date', 'desc'), 'sort-asc': sorted('date', 'asc')}" class="sortable">
     <a href="#" ng-click="setSort('date')">Date</a>
</th>
```

Here's the setSort code:

```
$scope.setSort = function(field) {
     if ($scope.sort.field == field)
          $scope.sort.dir = ($scope.sort.dir == 'desc') ? 'asc' : 'desc';
     else
          $scope.sort.field = field;
     $scope.update();
};
```

and sorted

```
$scope.sorted = function(field, dir) {
     return ($scope.sort.field == field && $scope.sort.dir == dir);
};
```

On initial pageload, the default sort (date-asc) is applied to the data within the table however the sort-asc is not applied.
When changing the sort column, it will display fine - it's just the initial page load.

How can I get angular to evaluate correctly on pageload?

Comment: what does `sorted` function contains?

Comment: Added to the post body @PankajParkar

Comment: Can't reproduce the problem here ~ http://plnkr.co/edit/lOYj7nFZstMfuGRBR4th?p=preview (`.sort-asc` has a pink background, `.sort-desc` a light blue).

Comment: nothing obvious in the code shown... I suspect problem is elsewhere

Comment: @Phil, @charlietfl - you guys are correct. Longer answer below, but in short I had `$scope.sort = {}` and `$scope.sort = function()...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more poking around I figured out the issue: I had `$scope.sort` defined twice, once as an object and once as a function.

For some reason, it was working once `$scope.sort.dir` and `$scope.sort.field` were re-defined by changing the sorting but the original values were overwritten by my function definition.

Lesson learnt - be more careful with variables names.